# java 17 feature Vector Vs. Java Util Vector, same or different?

Tags: java, java-16, java-17

All of the new features in the new Java 17 SDK get me excited, but the "Vector" really gets me confused:

Based on the official docs, the Vector is to target the CPU intensive computation (e.g. hard-core Math calculation), and this can be used for developing applications such as ML algorithms

The term "Vector" triggered a thing in my mind, which is the class in the Util module, and it is like "ArrayList", but thread-safe. I casually use this in my code when dealing with concurrency situations.

Now, I'm confused. when talking about the "Vector" in the latest Java 17, these two "Vector" are the same thing? or totally different?

Comment: Are you talking about [jdk.incubator.vector](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1JeoNr6-pZw)? Because that's not "a Vector class", that's a _library_ called Vector.

Comment: yes. that is the new "Vector" that I'm talking about. this one is inside standard jdk built

Comment: Right, so: that was the answer. It's an entire API called "the Vector API", which fairly obviously has nothing to do with the `java.utils.Vector` object class.

Comment: How big are the chances that a new feature introduced in 2021 has anything to do with an ancient class that became legacy in 1998?

Comment: If you're regularly using `java.util.Vector` because it is 'thread-safe', you should stop using it now and use one of the more appropriate (and usually better performing) replacements.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I understand the "CopyOnWriteArrayList" performs in a similar way, but I don't think the "Vector" needs to be abandoned. instead, it really depends on the usage pattern. my simple rule is that " if I have much more reads than writes, use CopyOnWriteArrayList, otherwise use Vector."

Comment: The new `jdk.incubator.vector` library implements access to _vector instructions_ provided by modern processors that can be used to accelerate numerical computations through hardware-level parallelism.  See, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_processor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> java 17 feature Vector Vs. Java Util Vector, same or different?

They are different APIs. Java vector API was released with Java 16. Check [JEP 338: Vector API (Incubator)](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/338) to learn more about Java vector API. With Java 17, the vector API has been enhanced for performance and implementation. One of the enhancements is to translate byte vectors to and from boolean arrays.